# Share a SESSION across multiple servers with different domains

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm having a little problem. I am developing an application in PHP that is divided into modules. Each module is completely independent, is on a separate server and has an own domain. eg:

www.moduloprincipal.com.br, www.modulo2.com.br, www.modulo3.com.br, etc ...

The problem is that I need that when a user to authenticate to one of the modules (either) the user can access the same user other modules without having to authenticate again.

Currently each application is on a different server, but if necessary they are in the same server, it would not be a problem.

IMPORTANT:

1. Read several threads, but found no solution really safe. Will be interesting to use OAuth?
2. Currently the application uses $ _SESSION to authenticate users, but you can use $ _COOKIE smoothly.
3. I'm using CodeIgniter

Translated by Google Translate. Sorry ...

Comment: For reasons why OAuth is not the right choice (and for an alternative), see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033026/sso-with-cas-or-oauth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033026/sso-with-cas-or-oauth)

Answer (score 11):

Two options from the top of my head that you can explore:

- Set all servers the same path for saving its session data, see
  [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) directive. That location could be a NFS share
  or a NAS location that all your servers could access.
- The other option is to [implement a database session handler](http://www.charles-reace.com/blog/2009/10/20/implementing-a-database-based-session-handler/), so
  the session data could be shared among all
  your servers accessing the same database server. So take a look at PHP docs
  for [custom session handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php).

Comment: He could also have one server act as an API that handles all the session information.