# Serve a web page that gives access to several different local web servers

Tags: python, apache, proxy, webserver

I'm sure this question is easily googleable, but I can't seem to find the right query to find the answer I want.

I'm running several apps on my home server that all serve their own website for admin and info purposes. Currently I access them all from the internet using http://MyHouseServerAddress.com:8080 etc. Where 8080 is replaced with 8081, 8082 etc. for each app. They all have their own usernames and passwords and some of them use SSL

What I want is to have a single access point, e.g. http://MyHouseServerAddress.com which gives me access to each app. Each app will have a link on that page which will take you to that app's website as if it were just a page on the main site. However... I want the single access point to be password protected and SSL'd, BUT I want to remove the passwords from all the apps as they would be accessed through the single "portal" of the initial page which is password protected and SSL'd. I.e. each app would still serve on it's original port, but that port would no longer be accessible via the internet, instead any traffic from that port would be routed through the single access point.

What I'm trying to do it get a single password login, preferably via SSL to my home server which gives me access to all my other serving apps but also secures them all behind the single login.

Can this be done with a python script or a C# app for instance running some sort of proxy or port forward script? Or would running an Appache server that can redirect traffic through itself work? I'm happy to write code to solve the problem if needed.

I hope this makes sense!

I'm running W7 on my home server.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a portal with single sign-on. I haven't tried, but you might get away with implementing oauth on your sites and have the main site be the provider.

Other way would be to use soemthing like CAS.

Look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033026/sso-with-cas-or-oauth) for options.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Apache+PHP on port 80, install [PHP Web Proxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/) on it, allow local access to your apps (so they allow access without password from localhost) and secure this gateway with [.htaccess and .htpasswd](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/auth-htpasswd.html), or another way.

This is most simple solution for home using. Good enterprise solution would be SSO, bad it is not simple.

Comment: That looks perfect from the description. I'll try it tonight.
Thanks!