# CAS server with SAML.2

Tags: cas

I'm starting to work with CAS on my company. This is totally new for me, so I had to read lot of documents and how to's to have an idea of how CAS works.

So, we have to provide a single sign on service in our server to a company with two different applications. One of those, uses SAML2.
My CAS server is now working against a MySQL database, so I'll have the users of those 2 apps on my database to provide authentication service.

What I don't get clear is about SAML. All the tutorials I've read about SAML2 integrated with CAS 4.0.0 are using Google Accounts. I don't know why! I have some SAML2 configuration on a xml on my CAS directories, but I don't know how to prove if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to authenticate both of the applications using your single database, CAS is enough, SAML not required. With SAML you can connect to an external application(which supports SAML), both might be having their own internal authentication, but they will commnicate each other through SAML2 protocol/agreement

CAS is ideal ,if you want to setup a web single sign-on to different web applications (exclusively for a single institution), which all use the same authentication (DB, LDAP or whatever). With this the authentication will be centralized for all these different applications.

For users from another external  institution to use your web application, SAML would be the choice, provided the External application also should support SAML.